# Migrating a C# library to Windows Phone

Tags: c#, file-upload, windows-phone-8, httprequest, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to migrate a Windows C# library to Windows Phone 8 and I'm forced to make some changes in how the library gets data from an online URI.

I'm using the BCL's `HttpClient` to perform my data retrieval and everything's fine for now.

The library also requires an upload feature, and I can't find a way to do this using th `HttpClient`.

Here's the code:

```
// Client setup
var httpclient = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, string.Format(SubmitURI, value));
// Add the headers    
request.Headers.Add("header", header);
var postData = GetPostData();
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
// Side question -> Content is null here!
request.Content.Headers.Add("ContentType", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + Boundary);
// BEGIN ORIGINAL CODE
var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
stream.Close();
// END ORIGINAL CODE
// Get response
var response = await httpclient.SendAsync(request);
var responseContent = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()).ReadToEnd();
```

Between the *BEGIN ORIGINAL CODE* and *END ORIGINAL CODE* comments, there's the code that I'm not able to migrate, so that you can understand what it does and I may need to make it work on WP.

The other of the code is already working on WP, except for the

```
request.Content.Headers.Add("ContentType", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + Boundary);
```

because, for some reasons, `request.Content` is *null*.

So my question is: how can I migrate those 3 lines to WP using `HttpClient` (or any better way)?

And, as a little side question, why is `request.Content` null?

EDIT: based on @Johan van der Slikke's answer I've edited my code. It compiles, but the server reports that no file was uploaded, so I guess that there are still some issues.

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
request.Content = streamContent;
request.Content.Headers.Add("ContentType", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + Boundary);
// Get response
var response = await httpclient.SendAsync(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your stream in the `StreamContent` class (a subclass of `HttpContent`) and send it with the `HttpClient` using the `PostAsync` or `PutAsync` methods.

### Edit

You don't need to use `HttpRequestMessage`.

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
// Get response
var response = await httpclient.PostAsync(streamContent)
```

Also you don't need to create a `MemoryStream` with your byte array. You can wrap it in a `ByteArrayContent` directly.

```
var response = await httpclient.PostAsync(new ByteArrayContent(data))
```

Maybe (because I see you using multipart/form-data header) you should use `MultipartFormDataContent` classes or `FormUrlEncodedContentClasses`.

Comment: So there's no need to use `request.GetRequestStream()` but I only need to create a new `Stream` and wrap it into a `StreamContent`, right?

Comment: Indeed. But if your `GetPostData()` returns a string you could also use a the `StringContent` object, removing the need to create a `Stream`.

Comment: I've updated the question because I've tried what you said but the server says that no file was uploaded

Answer (score 0):

You can send multi-part content like this,

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var content = new MultipartContent();
content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(data));

var response = await client.PostAsync(SubmitUrl, content);
```

However, I am curious what media type your "PostData" is.  You may want to set the content-type header on the ByteArrayContent.